# What is the Möbius function of substrings?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, posets, mobius-inversion

Define a poset on the set of all finite binary strings, defined by $a \le b$ whenever $b = uav$ for (possibly empty) binary strings $u, v$.

What is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Special_elements) of this poset?

Comment: Have you computed examples (up to a certain rank, say)? Does it appear to have all Mobius function values in $\{0,1,-1\}$?

Comment: This problem was solved by Ander Björner, The Möbius function of factor order, *Theoretical Computer Science* **117** (1993), 91-98. In particular, the Möbius function assumes only the values $-1,0,1$. It is also Exercise 3.134(b) in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second edition.

Comment: Thank you prof. Stanley, I should have searched in your book before asking. Do you want to put this as an answer, or is this question off-topic for this site so I delete it?

Comment: I can put it as an answer, though it is only providing a reference and not doing any mathematics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem was solved by [Anders Björner, The Möbius function of factor order, *Theoretical Computer Science* **117** (1993), 91-98](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(93)90305-D). In particular, the Möbius function assumes only the values $-1,0,1$. It is also Exercise 3.134(b) in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second edition.